# iOS parser alloc breakpoint

Tags: ios, parsing, asynchronous, rss, breakpoints

```
.h
@class HtmlParser
@interface ClassName : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource>
{
NSString *img;
HtmlParser *htmlParser;
}
```

: )

```
.M
- (NSString*)img
{
 if (img!=nil) return img; 
   if (_description!=nil)
   { 
//    NSString* description = [NSString stringWithString:_description];
htmlParser = [[HtmlParser alloc] loadHtmlByString:(NSString*) _description];
   }
return img;
}
```

I am trying to initialize HtmlParser with the contents of description. "description" is RSS html loaded asynchronously, started in the tableViewController.

I get a breakpoint with or without the NSString* description. '-[HtmlParser loadHtmlbyString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75aa9b0'... That's all the debugging I know how to do. Breakpoints are enabled for all exceptions.

-the method in .m is called in the viewController's cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    ClassName *object = _objects[indexPath.row];

NSString *i = object.img;
    UIImage* iG = [UIImage imageWithData:
                [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:i]]];
cell.imageView.image = iG;
```

Its messy so let me know if further clarification is needed.

```
.h
@interface HtmlParser: NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>
{
ET Cetera
}
    - (id) loadHtmlByString:(NSString *)string;
```

Comment: Where do you define loadHtmlbyString?

Comment: I put it up there. I omitted it for simplification's sake.

Comment: The way you originally posted it, it appeared that loadHtmlbyString was in your HtmlParser class, but with your update it's clear that it's not, so rmaddy's answer has pinpointed your problem.

Comment: Is not your loadHtmlbyString method in the wrong class (ClassName rather than HtmlParser)? Is so you should accept rmaddy's answer. You should change the things I mentioned too, but the main problem is the method being in the wrong class.

Comment: Sorry... he gave the right answer, based on my misplaced id..."...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the method in question:

```
htmlParser = [[HtmlParser alloc] loadHtmlbyString:(NSString*) _description];
```

It shouldn't have the (NSString *) in there. It should be:

```
htmlParser = [[HtmlParser alloc] loadHtmlbyString: _description];
```

But, is loadHtmlbyString an init method? If so, then you should start the name with init, and you should also adhere to the naming conventions by capitalizing all the words in the name (including By).

Comment: Thank you! There turned out to be case insensitivity (and so I will reinforce that habit), and thank you for helping with the method format.

Answer (score 1):

The 'loadHtmlbyString`method is not a method of the`HtmlParser`class, it is a method of your`ClassName` class.

Don't you get a compiler warning on this line:

```
htmlParser = [[HtmlParser alloc] loadHtmlbyString:(NSString*) _description];
```

Look at the .h for the HtmlParser class and see what methods are defined for that class.